# How to get the ID of a newly created document during a Transaction in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm reading the docs on [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js_1) operations, and I figured the `t.set()` method would work similar to the `docReference.set()` documented in the the [Add data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_7) page.

To my surprise, it doesn't:

```js
const newCustomerRef = db.collection('customers').doc();

await db.runTransaction(t => {
  const res = t.set(newCustomerRef, formData)
  console.log(res)
});
```

The `res` object above (return value of `t.set()`) contains a bunch of props that looks obfuscated, and it doesn't look as if it's intended for you to work with them.

Is there any way to get the ID of the newly created document **within a Transaction**?

#### Update

What I'm trying to achieve is to have multiple data operations in 1 go, and have everything reverted back if it fails.

As per Doug answer, if `newCustomerRef` already contains the ID, it seems what I am missing is to delete it during the catch block in case the transaction fails:

```
try {
  const newCustomerRef = db.collection('customers').doc();

  await db.runTransaction(t => {
    const res = t.set(newCustomerRef, formData)
    console.log(res)
  });
} catch (e) {
  newCustomerRef.delete()

  //...error handling...
}
```

This is sort of a manual thing to do, feels a little hacky. Is there a way to delete it automatically if the transaction fails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newCustomerRef` already contains the ID.  It was generated randomly on the client as soon as `doc()` was called, before the transaction ever started.

```
const id = newCustomerRef.id
```

If a transaction fails for any reason, the database is unchanged.

Comment: I see. It seems I didn't understand the docs properly. If the transaction fails, I suppose I am to delete the customer in the `catch` block, right?  I'll update my question for more details of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If a transaction fails for any reason, the database is unchanged.  That's the main point of a transaction - everything works or nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The operation to add the document is performed in the `set(..)` call. This means by using `set()` on the transaction, everything is rolled back should the transaction fail.

This means in the following example

```
...
await db.runTransaction(t => {
    t.set(newCustomerRef, formData)
    ... do something ...

    if (someThingWentWrong) {
       throw 'some error'
    }
});
```

Should someThingWentWrong be true, no document will have been added.